# Adding default values in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist

I have a product with following format:

```
public Item(String barcode, double price, int inStock) {
    if (barcode == null) {
        barcode = "";
    }
    if (price < 0) {
        price = 0;
    }
    if (inStock < 0) {
        inStock = 0;
    }
    this.barcode = barcode;
    this.price = price;
    this.inStock = inStock;
}
```

And an `ArrayList` to store the items in another class:

```
public class Inventory {
    private ArrayList<Item> currentInventory;

    public Inventory() {
        this.currentInventory = new ArrayList<Inventory>();
    }

    /**
     * Adds default products to the inventory
     */
    public void inventoryDefault() {    
        this.currentInventory("JMS343", 100.00, 5);
        this.currentInventory("RQ090", 50.00, 20);  
    }
```

I cannot figure out how to add 2 items as defaults, or always in the `currentInventory`, until removed by the user. I have also tried:

```
public void inventoryDefault() {    
    this.currentInventory.add(JMS343, 100.00, 5);
    this.currentInventory.add(RQ090, 50.00, 20);    
}
```

This, however, shows an error that `JMS343` and `RQ090` cannot be resolved to variables. I thought I was creating them at this point, since it is just a String. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Working solution as shown below:

```
        public void inventoryDefault() {    
            this.currentInventory.add(new Item("JMS343", 100.00, 5));
            this.currentInventory.add(new Item("RQ090", 50.00, 20));    
        }
```

Comment: You forgot the surrounding double quotes. **"** JMS343 **"**

Comment: You also forgot the `Item` constructor.

Comment: I did the double quotes in my first try. Tried it with and without and showed that in my examples.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but isn't the constructor for Items the "public Items(x, x, x)" at the beginning of the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this to the constructor of the `Inventory` class

```
public Inventory() {
        this.currentInventory = new ArrayList<Inventory>();
        this.currentInventory.add(new Item("JMS343", 100.00, 5));
        this.currentInventory.add(new Item("RQ090", 50.00, 20);
    }
```

Comment: This worked exactly as asked for! I added it to my code above. Will accept as answer when it allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct `Item` objects with the constructor to add them to the `ArrayList`. E.g.

```
public void inventoryDefault() {    
    currentInventory.add(new Item("JMS343", 100.00, 5);
    currentInventory.add(new Item("RQ090", 50.00, 20);
}
```

Or add an appropriate function to `Inventory` that may also be useful otherwise :

```
public void addItem(String barcode, double price, int inStock) {
    Item item = new Item(barcode, price, inStock);
    currentInventory.add(item);
}

public void inventoryDefault() {    
    addItem("JMS343", 100.00, 5);
    addItem("RQ090", 50.00, 20);
}
```